# How can I download a single raw file from a private Bitbucket repo using the command line?

Tags: curl, command-line, bitbucket

I'd like to download a file from a private repo without cloning the whole thing.

All of the results I can find suggest the same thing: create an App Password in Bitbucket, then use that password along with your username. I tried it:

```
curl -u my_username:app_password https://bitbucket.org/my_username/the_repo/raw/commit_sha/the_file
```

I know the URL is at least reasonable because I can view it in a browser if I'm logged into Bitbucket.

But running the curl command fails with an error:

```
Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for API authentication.
See our community post for more details: https://atlassian.community/t5/x/x/ba-p/1948231
App passwords are recommended for most use cases and can be created in your Personal settings:
https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/
For more details on API authentication methods see our documentation:
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#authentication
```

The second link mentioned has a section about [App Passwords](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#app-passwords) that doesn't say much about how to actually use them.

Using the App Password with `git clone` works fine, but I can't figure out how to get it to work with curl.

Comment: Have you read through the [API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#authentication) linked in the last line of the error?

Comment: Yep, it has a section about App Passwords that pretty much explains what they are, says how to create one, and then says to plug it into an app. There's nothing I can see about actual usage.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
curl -u <user>:<app_password> -L -O https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<org>/<repo>/src/<branch>/<file>
```

[Bitbucket REST API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-source/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-src-commit-path-get)

Answer (score 0):

The Only url which will work to download single file from bit-bucket is this.

### Syntax:

curl -L -o output.txt -u username:password "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/username/repo/src/branch/path/to/file.txt"

### Example: File downloaded successfully -Command Ran below

[Mon Jul 17 10:24:59 jenkins@5e06d0d3b9b0:jenkins_server:192.168.0.7:~/ansible-scripts ] $ curl -L -o output.txt -u abhilash-jain:ATBBXpY5ZSw-test-password-8H7923C50D "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/abhilash-jain/abhi-test1/src/main/help.txt"

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    27  100    27    0     0     25      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    25
[Mon Jul 17 10:28:30 jenkins@5e06d0d3b9b0:jenkins_server:192.168.0.7:~/ansible-scripts ] $

Comment: can you delete this answer ASAP ? you have posted your actual password here !!

Comment: This is just sample file,no data